# how to include jquery in google gadget?

Tags: jquery, google-gadget

i'm writing a small google gadget, how could i include the jquery library?
The gadget comes in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="hello world example" />
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[

code here!

]]></Content>
</Module>
​
```

The css and javascript can be included, but i don't know how to include jquery library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="hello world example" />
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
code here!

]]></Content>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to write inline scripting. i.e., you can put the content of jquery.js(the content is very less hardly some 100s of lines) under `<script>//paste raw script here!..</script>` tags in your file itself.